# Getting a mean app up and running

Tags: nginx, ssh, server, ubuntu-14.04, mean-stack

I have installed the MEAN stack on ubuntu 14.04 using digital ocean as my server. I am able to view the MEAN home page when I go to my IP address port 3000 (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3000). My three basic questions to get from here to seeing my app at my domain name are: 1) how to get my IP address to display my page without adding a port number? (I have seen a lot of answers concerning a proxy with nginx and I have tried them, but something is not working, I just get the "welcome to nginx" screen rather than my app). second how to keep my app running when I log out of the console, it runs fine if I open up a ssh connection to my server and run grunt, but when I close the ssh window, I can no longer visit my IP address and see my app. my last question is, when I do see my app it's the "MEAN" homepage, if I put an html file in the public folder of my mean app I can go to http://:3000/example.html to see it, but I would like to know how to make that file the default/primary one rather than the mean homepage. Thank you in advance for the answers to one or all of these.

Comment: As you're asking effectively 3 different questions, please split this into 3 different questions. That way you will also be able to get much clearer and more focused answers.

Comment: Also at least for the first question, please post your current nginx configuration so we can try and find the error.